# How do I enter content in a richtext editor to a database in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, content-management-system

I am trying to build a simple CMS as a project to help me learn and improve my asp.net and c# skills. I have set up my web form and am entering the content into the database using the following code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set up connection string.
        const string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CMSDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

        //SQL statement
        string statement = "INSERT INTO PageContent(Title, Content, Image) VALUES (@title, @content, @image)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement);

        //Escape special characters
        string content = Regex.Escape(ftbContent.Text);

        //Add contents of form to the database.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtTitle.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", txtImage.Text);

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            //do exception handling stuff
        }
    }
```

I have tried using the Regex.Escape method to escape the html that is being created by the richtext editor but it's not working. Can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong please?

I am getting the following server error: 
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ftbContent="

Thanks.

Comment: Can u Pease tell me the Sample Value content after performing the RegEx. ftbContent.Text is shoud having only Text it won't be any html thinks

Comment: What is your problem ? Are you receiving an error message ? Trying to push HTML content through the request may cause the request validation to fail.

Comment: @Bartdude Yes I am getting a server error that says: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ftbContent="<strong style="font-...").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enable this

We have to add just One Line of Code in Web.config file and one property in Default.aspx form (Page with Rich Text Editor).
That is :

```
in web.config:



<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and in Page directive:

```
ValidateRequest = "false"

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: The issue was the Text propert is Having the HTml Tags, Once you enable this you can send the Data to Server

Comment: Be carefull though and only deactivate request validation on pages where users are supposed to input html content. Note that it doesn't dispense you you from using htmlencode/htmldecode, check for eventual malicious code or use of undesired html tags

Answer (score 0):

try HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode

> string content = Server.HtmlEncode(ftbContent.Text);

Comment: show me your html, it always worked for me, lets see why is it not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content);
```

Note:by this work any time you loading your content from database,  your text dosn't any format as a string sequence